# Use the same column spacing as another QGridLayout with a different number of columns

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I have a `QGridLayout` with 5 columns, and widgets with fixed widths are in columns 1 and 3, so that resizing the window will change the padding around them.

I would like to have another `QGridLayout` above that, but this time with 3 columns, where the 3rd one stretches to the end. I can't seem to get it to match the other layout though, and I'm wondering if there's anything I could do.

Here's an image of the box. The red arrows are the resizing width, and I'd like the green arrow to match those if possible. If I set the column stretch to `1|2` or `1|1|4` it resizes at the same rate, but is a bit far offset to the right.

[image]

I'm still learning Qt so it'd also be nice to know how how most people deal with issues like this.

Comment: Use one main grid-layout. Put the four top widgets in a child layout which spans all the colums other than the first.

Answer (score 0):

You should nest the `QGridLayout` with 5 columns in another `QGridLayout`.

- The first column will be empty, just like in the 3-column grid
- The second column will have the labels for the first column of controls
- The last column will contain the nested grid

  - That first column will contain the first row of controls (without labels)
  - The rest of that grid will be same as before

This way your controls should line up. If you want to line up the labels (take into account the right-alignment) you should use a column span of 2 on the outer grid